# How to properly manipulate checked attribute in radio input elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Basically I'm trying to set the **checked** attribute (the one for radio input) according to the selected process **VC** attribute. But it is not working. Do you guys have any idea how to make it work properly?

Component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const processes = [
    { id: 1, VC: true },
    { id: 2, VC: false },
    { id: 3, VC: false },
    { id: 4, VC: true }
  ];
  const [selectedProcess, setSelectedProcess] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Radio</h1>
      <select
        className="form-control"
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedProcess(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option></option>
        {processes.map((process) => (
          <option key={process.id} value={process.id}>
            {process.id}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <input
        id="customCheck1"
        type="checkbox"
        className="custom-control-input"
        checked={selectedProcess !== "" ? selectedProcess.VC : false}
        name="VC"
      />
      <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="customCheck1">
        Vacuum
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Checked attribute:

```
checked={selectedProcess !== "" ? selectedProcess.VC : false}
```

As you can see, by default I'm setting it as false and, If I select a process, e.g with id 4, the radio input should be checked. If necessary, I have the code in CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit focused-napier-infzf]

Answer (score 1):

The `value` of your `option`s are `process.id` not the process itself. so `selectedProcess` will be either `''`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`. So `selectedProcess.VC` will always be undefined. You'll need to check like `checked={selectedProcess !== '' ? selectedProcess : false}` for it to work.

I suggest doing: `checked={!!selectedProcess}`